# PHP change numbered array into an array with keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in PHP like this:

```
$arr=["abc","def","ghi"];
```

and I want to later on convert it into an array with keys, like this:

```
$arr=["first" => "abc", "second" => "def", "third" => "ghi"];
```

How can I easily convert the first array into the second? In other words, how can I add keys to a numeric array?

Many thanks.

Comment: `$arr=("abc","def","ghi");` is not an array but a syntax error. I think you meant `$arr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];`

Comment: Is the array fixed length? Do the keys have to be "first", "second" ... ?

Comment: Another thing to note that a "numbered" array actually is the same thing as an array with keys.  In a "numbered" array, the keys are automatically generated and incremented, where is when you specify a key...it's custom.  There's no difference between the two, they're both arrays, just different ways of labelling each item.  With that said, you should rarely use the actual word/string "first", "second", etc as your keys and instead use the numbers to more easily use the array in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_combine`](http://php.net/array-combine) to use one array for keys and another for values:

```
$arr = ["abc", "def", "ghi"];
$keys = ["first", "second", "third"];
$arr = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

Comment: Might want to make a note that that array syntax is only supported in PHP 5.4+

Answer (score 3):

with [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php):

```
$new_array = array_combine($keys, $arr);
```

(note that `$keys` should be a numeric array too, its values will be used as keys in the new array)